# Se repiten los datos en consulta de MySQL

Tags: mysql

Tabla 1:

```
|---------------------------|
| cedula | nombre | celular |
|---------------------------|
| 111111 | juan   | 1111111 |
|---------------------------|
| 111111 | juan   | 1111111 |
|---------------------------|
```

Tabla 2:

```
|----------------------------|
| cedula | dia    | hora     |
|----------------------------|
| 111111 | lunes  | 9:00 am  |
|----------------------------|
| 111111 | jueves | 10:00 am |
|----------------------------|
```

Consulta:

```
SELECT t1.cedula, t1.nombre, t1.celular, t2.dia, t2.hora,
FROM reg_usuario t1
LEFT JOIN reg_visita t2 ON t1.cedula = t2.cedula
```

Resultado:

```
|-------------------------------------------------|
| cedula | nombre | celular | dia     | hora      |
|-------------------------------------------------|
| 111111 | juan   | 1111111 | lunes   | 9:00 am   |
|-------------------------------------------------|
| 111111 | juan   | 1111111 | jueves  | 10:00 am  |
|-------------------------------------------------|
| 111111 | juan   | 1111111 | lunes   | 9:00 am   |
|-------------------------------------------------|
| 111111 | juan   | 1111111 | jueves  | 10:00 am  |
|-------------------------------------------------|
```

Sonará muy boba y/o elemental la pregunta pero ¿Por qué se repiten los datos? ¿Qué estoy haciendo mal? He probado con los diferentes `JOIN` y me sale igual, también he probado agregando `GROUP BY t1.cedula` pero solo me muestra un registro por cédula.

Comment: ¿Por qué se repiten los datos en Tabla1? Si varios registros de tabla1 representan una misma entidad, por ejemplo, una persona, qué campos son los que servirían para determinar que varios registros en realidad son una misma entidad?

Comment: ¿Por qué `Juan` está dos veces en Tabla1? ¿No debería estar sólo una vez?

Comment: Un mismo usuario se puede registrar cuantas veces quiera y puede elegir los días y las horas que quiera. Pero creo que ya sé cuál es mi error, si un usuario ya está registrado, no debería volver a ingresar sus datos sino solo la fecha y hora de la nueva visita.

Comment: En alguna tabla donde registres las visitas solo deberías estar almacenando como llave foránea el id del usuario, eso ayudaría a no tener valores duplicados en una primer instancia

Comment: Tienes que tener llaves primarias y llaves foráneas para hacer un buen selecta de ambas... como tienen relación las tablas? no hay... por eso son las llaves.

Answer (score 0):

Es por el producto cartesiano,
al hacer el join estás combinando entonces las siguientes parejas:

```
|---------------------------|
| cedula | nombre | celular |
|---------------------------|
| 111111 | juan   | 1111111 |+ juan en lunes 9:00 am 
  111111 | juan   | 1111111  + juan en jueves 10:00 am
```

y lo mismo para el segundo registro, aunque es igual, es un registro que coincide en el join, entonces por eso tienes el resultado de arriba dos veces, porque estás haciendo un join con múltiples campos que coinciden, a mi me parece que lo que hay que hacer es justamente una tabla de registro de clientes con el Primary key el campo cédula, o signups y luego una tabla más para las asistencias, que precisamente registra la cédula cada vez, pero ahí tienes un campo para agrupar si necesitas.